# Changing how font looks in Microsoft Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, expression, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder

Is there a way to be able to change how the font looks in the expression depending on the data output and on which row?  As you can see below, I change the font to be red depending on the outcome. But i would also like to be able to manipulate each row.

[image]

[image]

I thought i could add more into the expression to manipulate whatever the output is, but I got an error when doing that.

[image]
[image]

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first 3 expressions you have

`Fields!Score_Interpretation.Value`

in the last three

`Fields!Score_Interpretation_.Value`

just remove the extra `_` as the error says, this field does not exist.

Comment: Oh man i cannot believe i missed something that small.  Was racking my brain over this.  Thanks.

Comment: we've all been there!